# Problem parcing json

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

Не получается использовать данные, полученные через Retrofit + OkHTTP3
Получаю данные в приложение(в Loge вывожу, все данные присутствуют), не получается использовать эти данные, вроде создал модели, чтобы данные выводить на экран(возможно проблема в них),

Вот код:

**Models:**

```
data class Child(
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    val childData: ChildData?
)

data class ChildData(
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    val title: String?,
    @SerializedName("num_comments")
    @Expose
    val numComments: Int?,
    @SerializedName("created")
    @Expose
    val created: Int?,
    @SerializedName("author")
    @Expose
    val author: String?,
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    val url: String?
)


data class GlobalData(
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    val globalData: News?
)

data class News(
    @SerializedName("children")
    @Expose
    val data: List<Child>?
)
```

**Network**

```
interface ApiNews {
    @GET("top.json")
    suspend fun getNews(
    ): List<GlobalData>
}




data class Event<out T>(val status: Status, val data: T?, val error: Error?) {

    companion object {
        fun <T> loading(): Event<T> {
            return Event(Status.LOADING, null, null)
        }

        fun <T> success(data: T?): Event<T> {
            return Event(Status.SUCCESS, data, null)
        }

        fun <T> error(error: Error?): Event<T> {
            return Event(Status.ERROR, null, error)
        }
    }
}



object NetworkService {
    private const val BASE_URL = "https://www.reddit.com/"

    private val loggingInterceptor = run {
        val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        httpLoggingInterceptor.apply {
            httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }
    }

    private val baseInterceptor: Interceptor = invoke { chain ->
        val newUrl = chain
            .request()
            .url
            .newBuilder()
            .build()

        val request = chain
            .request()
            .newBuilder()
            .url(newUrl)
            .build()

        return@invoke chain.proceed(request)
    }

    private val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient
        .Builder()
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor(baseInterceptor)
        .build()

    fun retrofitService():ApiNews {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()
            .create(ApiNews::class.java)
    }
}



enum class Status {
    SUCCESS,
    ERROR,
    LOADING
}
```

ViewModels:

```
class ActivityViewModel : NewsViewModel() {
    val simpleLiveData = MutableLiveData<Event<List<GlobalData>>>()

    fun getNews() {
        requestWithLiveData(simpleLiveData) {
            api.getNews()
        }
    }
}

abstract class NewsViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var api: ApiNews = NetworkService.retrofitService()

    fun <GlobalData> requestWithLiveData(
        liveData: MutableLiveData<Event<List<GlobalData>>>,
        request: suspend () -> List<GlobalData>
    ) {
        liveData.postValue(Event.loading())
        this.viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val response = request.invoke()

                if (!response.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    liveData.postValue(Event.success(response))

                } else {
                    liveData.postValue(Event.error(null))
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                liveData.postValue(Event.error(null))
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: В вопросе плохо отформатирован код, отсутствует json, который парсится (а без него проверить корректность ваших дата классов нельзя), нет вызова сети, нет четкого описания того, в чем именно заключается ошибка. А вот activity и adapter тут как раз нафиг не нужны. Исправьте все это и можно будет попробовать разобраться

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov вроде отформатировал, скажи, если что-то еще требуется и спасибо)

Comment: @Сергей Долгоруков  а что именно не получается? Ошибки? напишите какие. Покажите где в коде запрашиваете данные

Comment: @AVRamones да ошибок нету, в целом мне нужно установить в поля данные из интернета типо так: holder.titleTextView.text = news.globalData?.data?.get(position)?.childData?.title
        holder.sourceTextView.text = news.globalData?.data?.get(position)?.childData?.author   Добавил еще ViewModel, может это нужно вам

Comment: Вы данные-то точно получаете? Лог перед отправкой данных в адаптер что выводит?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov вроде это: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov вроде до адаптера не доходит даже, скорее всего проблема с List, но какими именно, и где я не найду...

Comment: Кажется, нашел первую ошибку. `ApiNews.getNews` у Вас возвращает `List<GlobalData>`, а должен просто `GlobalData`. Эта ошибка может быть и единственной.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov так, ну вроде всё окей, последняя ошибка большее не вылезает, приложение просто получает данные и всё в конце, пробблема теперь в адаптере, который начинает искать данные до того, как я их получу, E/RecyclerView: No layout manager attached; skipping layout

Comment: Это "E/RecyclerView: No layout manager attached; skipping layout" вполне нормально

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov подскажи плиз, как изменить адаптер теперь, у меня там везде List<GlobalData> стоял... Установить List<Child> или как?)

Comment: Это уже зависит от того, что отображать надо) Но скорее всего да,`List<Child>`

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov суть в том, что у меня есть подобное приложение, только там в json дается всего одна строка, то есть на подобии List<ChildData>, только здесь  List<ChildData> завернут во всякие массивы и тд, и я никак не могу добраться нормально к списку... Крч без изменений в глобальном плане, до сих пор ничего не выводится((